# How to create a custom TypeScript type error

Tags: typescript

I have the following code that throws my type error when a specific set of args have been passed.

This works as expected:

```
type CheckForIncompatibleArgs<Args> = Args extends { heading: false; link: true } ? "You cannot display a link without a heading" : Args;

type Display = {heading: boolean; link: boolean};

interface Props<T> {
    display: CheckForIncompatibleArgs<T>;
    hello: string;
}

const fn = <T extends Display>({display, hello}: Props<T>) => {
    console.log("display heading:", display.heading);
    console.log("display link:", display.link);
}

// ✅
fn({display: { heading: true, link: true}, hello: "yes"});
fn({display: { heading: true, link: false}, hello: "yes"}});

// ❌
fn({display: { heading: false, link: true}, hello: "yes"}});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=52&pln=16&pc=55#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawGIHsBOBJAdo9AWzAENgBLAIwBsIBBTAcwGcAeBlgPigF4oPmUCAA9gEXABNBAbygISE8rkYAuKADMS1ZhADcUakuRrgmAK7QAvlAD8UAEQBNdGaiISuXOmBRFzMNQkIFAkBkZQAO7kwHAuPqHyisr2UGoCugBQGaCQUAAi5P6BwXzSiUqqUJTo6LQe%20oa4xlU1dbiWmRlKYpiaiNAACpjoYGwAKtzSGVAzvoUBQWrwSGhYeATEZFS0AqwTmbNyENTU6GrMphWZllkEuBcauLxQe0Ki4lL588WcABTSfgWIAANEcTuhLGohiNxpwAJS8SbTWZ3Zi1CAAOlOjF%209kBxSOCgqKnsoPxQQx5WUcIOKPQ93RWPQOLx3yCYSaJLJbJAWKMNIyNwyAHphVBAKDkGXUuH%205JAalkVMqpgsoMazRVEEsoIQ4LU9hAEGY9ksAulsp5CsJSWV5ggaqMak02i1OuOp31huNllNnVFUEAMuRSmUAy1QRUQInKJ1aHQOzlQTXasEehxek2%20oA)

However, I need to nest `display` inside an `options` object, like this:

```
interface Props {
    options: {
        display: Display;
    };
    hello: string;
}
```

How do I do this while ensuring my type error still works?

Comment: I don't understand the problem ─ your later definition of Props does not show your error message (really a string literal type), only because you didn't use `CheckForIncompatibleArgs` in the interface declaration. If you did use it then your error message would appear as expected. [Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mZJn9m)

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike how strange!  You're right!  I've literally got this in my IDE right now not working!  Hopefully I just need to restart.  Thank you :)